# Statistical test to compare the grades of students in different course-sections?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, statistical-significance, inference

If we have multiple sections of the same course, and each section is being taught by a different instructor, what statistical test should we use **to answer the following question**:

Are the grades of the students in section `X` statistically significantly different from that of all other sections combined?

Comment: You need to specify more precisely what you mean by "different."  The textbook answer in the case where it means "different arithmetic mean" is to use Analysis of Variance, but there are many other ways in which grades can differ.  Would you like to clarify your question?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. By "different" I mean the students of one section have a higher or lower grades than the students of other sections.